# Zendesk API invalid response

Tags: jquery, api, zendesk, zendesk-api

I use standard example from Zendesk API documentation:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var subject = "Test ticket #ABC";
        var body = "This is test ticket #ABC";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://tmstest.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                var auth = "Basic " + $.base64.encode("email@gmail.com/token:XXXX");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({ "ticket": { "subject": subject, "comment": { "body": body } } }),
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                } else {
                    alert('Unexpected error.');
                }
            }
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log(data.ticket);
            })
            ;
    });
```

it added a ticket, but I error part is called. `textStatus` has "error" value, `jqXHR.status` is 0, `errorThrown` is empty string. What is wrong?

Comment: What about `errorThrown`? It's there for a reason, you should look at it, eg `console.error(textStatus, errorThrown)`. Are there any other errors in your browser's console?

Comment: errorThrown is empty

Comment: That seems unlikely. Can you please update your question to match what you currently have? And again, are there any other errors in your browser's console, including the _Network_ tab?

Comment: What does browser console show?  It should at least indicate a response code, and from there you can figure out if it's a payload issue, an authorization or permissions issue, error with server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is being initiated from outside of the Zendesk domain, you have to use Oauth based authentication for client-side requests.  See here for more details - https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/introduction#security-and-authentication

Comment: what does the network tab of the browser console return as the response code?